# Error: Request failed with status code 403 (GET)

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I encountered an error when I tried to call my GET `/dev/get-comments` endpoint from my API. Now, my API works since my other GET `/dev/get-posts` endpoint works fine, the only difference between the two is that the first endpoint uses a request body.

```
API.get("holler-api", "/get-comments", {
  body: {postId: this.props.post.postId}
}).then(result => {
  if(result.Count > 0) {
    this.setState({
      comments: result.Items
    });
  }
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

```
XHR GET https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/get-comments
[HTTP/2 403 Forbidden 23ms]
```

This was the request response that explained the error, not very helpful!

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 191 of the JSON data
{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
The Canonical String for this request should have been
'GET
/dev/get-comments
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, API gateway does not support request bodies for GET requests, so you need to use path parameters.
[image]

The solution was to convert all my GET lambda functions to use path parameters and call the API as such:

```
API.get("holler-api", `/get-comments/${this.props.post.postId}`)
.then(result => {
  if(result.Count > 0) {
    console.log(result.Items);
    this.setState({
      comments: result.Items
    });
  }
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```